# Using hibernate.c3p0 when creating a EntityManagerFactoryBean in Java

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, c3p0

I recently moved from the .Net world to the Java world.

I have build a core project which is to be used by multiple clients (web client, api, ...)

Doing so i got tired of having to configure my data access beans and connection strings in multiple projects. The goal is to include my "core-project.jar" and be able to use that without having to configure data access beans and connection strings.

I found this: (seems to have trouble with the webserver atm.)
http://www.baeldung.com/2011/12/13/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-3-1-and-jpa/

which resulted in this code which works and completes my goal.

**BaseRepository**

```
package com.company.core.data.repositories;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceUnit;

public abstract class BaseRepository {
    protected EntityManagerFactory emf;

    @PersistenceUnit
    public void setEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        this.emf = emf;
    }
}
```

**UserRepository**

```
package com.company.core.data.repositories;

import com.company.core.data.interfaces.IUserRepository;
import com.company.core.data.pojos.UserPojo;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import java.util.List;

@Component
public class UserRepository extends BaseRepository implements IUserRepository {
    public UserPojo getByEmail(String email) throws Exception {

        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        List<UserPojo> results = em.createQuery("FROM UserPojo u WHERE u.email = ?", UserPojo.class)
                .setParameter(1, email)
                .getResultList();
        em.close();

        return firstOrDefault(results);
    }

    public static <T> T firstOrDefault(List<T> list){
        if(list.size() > 0)
            return list.get(0);

        return null;
    }
}
```

**UserPojo**

```
package com.company.core.data.pojos;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table( name = "User" )
public class UserPojo {
    // ALL THE Properties
}
```

**EntityManagerFactoryConfiguration**

```
package com.company.core.configuration;

import java.util.Properties;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({"com.company.core.data"})
public class EntityManagerFactoryConfiguration {
    public EntityManagerFactoryConfiguration() {
        super();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"com.company.core.data.pojos"});

        final HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "false");
//        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.provider_class", "org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider");
//        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_size", "100");
//        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.min_size", "0");
//        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment", "1");
//        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period", "200");
//        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_statements", "0");
//        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.timeout", "300");
        em.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties);

        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/databasename?autoReconnect=true");
        dataSource.setUsername("user");
        dataSource.setPassword("password");

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource c3p0dataSource() {
        final com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClass("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/databasename?autoReconnect=true");
        dataSource.setUser("user");
        dataSource.setPassword("password");

        return dataSource;
    }


    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(final EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        final JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }
}
```

As you can i want to use hibernate.c3p0 for connection management.

commenting in the outcommented hibernateproperties results in:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1771)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:64)
    at com.company.core.data.repositories.UserRepository.getByEmail(UserRepository.java:30)
    at com.company.core.business.implementations.UserService.getByEmail(UserService.java:18)
    at com.company.api.UserController.getByEmail(UserController.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveHandlerMethodException(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:362)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.doResolveException(AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.java:60)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1183)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1020)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:283)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2463)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2452)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:235)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1435)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:61)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:118)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:689)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getConnection(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1418)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:606)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:526)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutAndMarkConnectionInUse(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:755)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:682)
    ... 59 more
```

i have also tried to create a c3p0 datesource (see method c3p0dataSource()9 with no luck either.

I think i might be in over my head, any guidance would be appreciated!!

**The xml configuration:**

**application-context.xml**

```
<beans:bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="persistenceUnitName" value="DataSource"/>
</beans:bean>
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
                                 http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">
    <persistence-unit name="DataSource">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/database?autoReconnect=true" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password" />

            <!-- Important -->
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="100" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="0" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="300" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="0" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="100" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Currently setting those properties will do nothing as you are injecting a datasource. Just create a `DataSource` which is an instance of the C3P0 class. Use `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource` instead as that is a proper connection pool.

Comment: I just tried that, but still get this exception. "com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source." :-( How does SessionFactory effect the EntityManagerFactory? Maybe the connection pool needs to be set deeper down in the EntityManagerFactory?

Comment: Add the full stack trace and the code/configuration you have tried. You shouldn't be messing around with the `c3p0` and `connection` properties in hibernate as you are managing the datasource yourself (well spring does it).

Comment: Hello! i updated my question with all code and full stacktrace

Comment: also this was using "com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"

Comment: i also added the xml configuration i'm trying to move away from

Comment: As mentioned you should remove the `c3p0` and `connection` properties as they break the integration. Also why aren't you using Spring Managed transactions, currently it looks like you are managing your own... So not sure why you even have a transaction manager in there... Also remove the `javax.persistence.jdbc` properties. Your datasource configuration should be solely in Spring.

Comment: Took me some time to realise, but i got it to work! Thank you! Next task is to get Spring to manage transactions.

Comment: That is quite easy. Add `@EnableTransactionManagement` and well that is pretty much it. Annotate your classes/methods with `@Transactional` and bingo transactions.

Comment: @heuts It would be nice to see your final code

Comment: You can set the outcommented properties directly on the com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource DataSource. e.g. dataSource.setMaxPoolSize(100);